# Serialize/deserialize private fields and autoproperties of an object

Tags: c#, serialization

Is there way to serialize private fields and autoproperties of an object?

The restriction is that I can't edit classes that i need to serialize which means:
1. I can't add any atributes on members (kinda datacontract)
2. I can't inherit it from an interface (kinda Ixmlserializable )
4. Add getter and setter properties for the fields
3. Class of the root object that i need to serialize is not even marked as serializable

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something like this (you'll have to get more creative if you have things like collections or non-serializable fields, but you get the idea):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (var field in typeof(Foo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    dict[field.Name] = field.GetValue(f);
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Basically you're ripping the fields out one at a time, dumping them into a dictionary, then serializing the dictionary.

Comment: But it suppose dealing with reflection be myself. This sounds like not a long time challenge but I'm just interesting is there any .net library that can provide this? As I understand (maybe i'm wrong) that the idea of the most of serialization libraries is not to use reflection bacuse it extremely decrease speed. So this is explanation for me why for example XMLSerializer, SharpSerializer do not "serialize private fields" even optionaly. But must be some serializers that provide this functionality (at least for compare with the other solutions). Do you know such?

Comment: Nope, I don't know of anything that does it automatically. Reflection is relatively slow, but unless you're micro-optimizing or working with a ton of data, it's probably good enough. There might be ways to avoid doing reflection over and over, using expression trees where you only use reflection once and compile and cache the lambdas, but I don't know if that would work with private fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the DefaultContractResolver to do (de)serialization of only fields without having to decorate the classes:

```
public class FieldsOnlyContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Cast<MemberInfo>().ToList();
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperty(member, MemberSerialization.Fields);
    }
}
```

Then, to use it, specify inside JsonConvert.(De)SerializeObject:

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                       ContractResolver = new FieldsOnlyContractResolver()
                   };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, jsonSettings);
var objAgain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjType>(json, jsonSettings);
```